# JinternalFrame with jtable, inside a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have this class and the other one to connect to database and show me a table of the database this part of program works pretty well the problem explained below ,but no:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.*;
public class ManagerInterface {
public static JFrame ManagerInterface = new JFrame("Manager Interface");

public ManagerInterface() {
    StartInterfaceGUI();
}

public static JFrame getframe() {
    return ManagerInterface;
}
private void StartInterfaceGUI() {



    ManagerInterface.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ManagerInterface.setSize(1600, 900);
    new ShowEmployee();
    ManagerInterface.setVisible(true);
}
}
public static void main(String []args)
{
   new ManagerInterface();
}
```

and this class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import GUIManager.ManagerInterface;

public class ShowEmployee {

public static JInternalFrame frame = new JInternalFrame();
public JTable table = new JTable();
public JFrame mainframe = new JFrame();

public ShowEmployee() {

    frame.add(table);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scroll, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setTitle("Employees");
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setClosable(true);
    frame.setMaximizable(true);
    frame.setIconifiable(true);
    frame.setSize(650, 400);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

           /* mainframe.add(frame);
    mainframe.setSize(650, 400);    //adding frame inside mainframe defined in this class
    mainframe.pack();
    mainframe.setVisible(true);*/


    //ManagerInterface.getframe().add(frame); //adding the internalframe to manager interface frame


}
 }
```

I use the ManagerInterface  as a container for ShowEmployee, in this way:

- in **ManagerInterface** I call a **JFrame**
- the class **ShowEmployee** is represented by a   JInternalFrame on which add a JTable.
- I add the **JInternalFrame** to the **frame** of **managerInterface class**, that is defined by the line **ManagerInterface.getframe.add.(frame)**,  inserted in ShowEmployee.

The problem is the following:

- if I define a frame(in this case mainframe) inside **ShowEmployee** and I add the **internalframe** i see this: 
  [image]
- however, if I add the JInternalFrame to the frame ManagerInterface I see this: 
  [image]

In other words,**i don't see the attributes row of the table** represented by the **ScrollPane**,it is not visible at the inside of the frame managerInterface, 
I define the scrollpane in this way, defined in ShowEmployee. 
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane (table); 
**frame.getContentPane (.) add (scroll BorderLayout.SOUTH);**

Comment: unrelated: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: All this code really seems unnecessary. Especially  when you are using third party libraries that we may or may not have to try and run the example. Also the problem doesn't seem to have anything to do with the database. You could have easily created [**a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using static names for the headers. For better help soon, try to create an MCTRE as shown in the link

Comment: code edited, @peeskillet

Comment: Your code seems to have a main method dangling out in the middle of no-where, outside of any class, and I'm not sure what other problems are present other than an over-use and miss-use of statics. You might want to fix this, to only post *real code*, code that compiles and runs.

Comment: please be sure to read the tutorial chapter on internalFrames (the tutorial is referenced in the swing tag wiki) - they are **not** meant to be added to anything else than a JDesktopPane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As @kleopatra noted, **follow** java naming convention. variables start with lower case.
2. Why in the world are you naming the `JFrame` `ManagerInterface` when the class name is `ManagerInterface`?
3. Why in the world do you have two `main` methods? You only need it in the `ManagerInterface`, the launching class.
4. **Just make `ShowEmployee` subclass `JInternalFrame`**. Then just add it to the `JFrame` (that you are going to name something else) that is in `ManagerInterface`

   ```
   public class ManagerInterface {
       private Frame frame;
       private ShowEmployees showEmployee;

       public ManagerInterface() {
           showEmployees = new ShowEmployees();

           frame = new JFrame("MagagerInterface");
           frame.add(new ShowEmployees());
           frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           frame.pack();
           frame.setLocationRelativTo(null);
           frame.setVisible(true);
       }
   }

   public class ShowEmployees extends JInternalFrame {
       public ShowEmployees() {

       }
   }
   ```
5. Adding on to 4. **You should be adding `JInternalFrame` to `JDesktopPane`s and not `JFrame`**

   ```
   JDesktopPane desktop;

   public ManagerInterface() {
       showEmployees = new ShowEmployees();
       desktop = new JDesktopPane();
       desktop.add(showEmployees);

       frame = new JFrame("MagagerInterface");
       frame.setContentPane(desktop);
       ....
   }
   ```
6. Run your Swing apps from the EDT

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
           public void run() {
               new ManagerInterface();
           }
       });
   }
   ```

   See [**Initial Threads**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)
7. The below doesn't cause a problem, but you should know that a parent can only have one parent container. So you trying to add the table to the frame *and* the scroll pane shouldn't be done. Just add the scroll pane

   ```
   frame.add(table);   <<---------------------Get Rid of MEEEE!
   JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
   frame.getContentPane().add(scroll, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   ```

---

Here is a running example with all the above mentioned fixes.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ManagerInterface {

    public JFrame frame = new JFrame("Manager Interface");

    private ShowEmployee showEmployee;
    private JDesktopPane desktop;

    public ManagerInterface() {
        showEmployee = new ShowEmployee();
        desktop = new JDesktopPane();
        desktop.add(showEmployee);

        frame = new JFrame("MagagerInterface");
        frame.setContentPane(desktop);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ManagerInterface();
            }
        });
    }
}

class ShowEmployee extends JInternalFrame {

    String[][] data = {{"Hello", "Hello", "Hello"},
    {"Hello", "Hello", "Hello"}};
    String[] cols = {"Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3"};

    public JTable table = new JTable(data, cols);

    public ShowEmployee() {

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        getContentPane().add(scroll);
        setTitle("Employees");
        setResizable(true);
        setClosable(true);
        setMaximizable(true);
        setIconifiable(true);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels just fixed :)

Comment: thank you,for answer,i forgot to cancel the main method on showEmployee, i used to do debug in my ide, i used to name managerInterface as the class name,because for me is easier,to remember.

Comment: @CiMat: also take care not to abuse the static modifier. You are doing this in the code you've posted.

Comment: why? @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: @CiMat: why avoid abusing the static modifier? Because this prevents you from encapsulating state and behavior, and will thus can seriously hamper your ability to enhance and modify your code. By introducing "global" variables, you also make it difficult if impossible to test your code well.

Comment: i'll prevent in future this.